# System Exception or Application Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, ejb

I am confused by a vague point in the definition and the possible impact of `Application Exceptions` and `System Exceptions` in `EJB`. In particular I cannot figure out if the Exception defined as:

```
public class SomeException extends Exception{
...
}
```

is going to be an `Application` or `System Exception`. According to the specification an `Application Exception` should always be defined with the annotation `@ApplicationException`. I infer hence that the above class is not an `Application Exception` even though it is a checked Exception. My questions coming out pertain to the correct Java Syntax and subsequently to the behaviour of the `EJB Container` in case this `Exception` is to be thrown within a business method of a `Session Bean` (not `Singleton` though):

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StatelessBean{

public void doStuff(){
throw new SomeException(); 
}

}
```

1) Should the `SomeException` be declared in the throw clause?

2) Does the `Container` discards the instance after the method `doStuff()` is called?

3) If  it is finally a `Sytem Exception` is my assumption correct, that a `System Exception` could be a checked and not `RuntimeException`?

**Update:**

To my opinion it is not definitely clear according to the spec that a checked Exception should always be an `Application Exception`. What if one would define a checked `RuntimeException`? Should it be included in `throw` of a method? Is it a `System` or `Application Exception`?

```
 public class SomeException extends RuntimeException{
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec says:

> Application exceptions that are checked exceptions may be defined as such by being listed in the throws clauses of the methods of the bean’s business interface, no-interface view, home interface, component interface, and web service endpoint. An appli- cation exception that is an unchecked exception is defined as an application exception by annotating it with the ApplicationException metadata annotation, or denoting it in the deployment descriptor with the application-exception element.

So, the above class is an Application exception, since it's a checked exception. And of course it must be listed in the throws clause of your method, otherwise the code won't compile. And no, the bean instance won't be discarded after this exception is thrown, as per the spec.

Comment: I still persist that it is not completelly clear even in the spec. I have read though in another resource that id a checked Exception is not annotated with @AppicationException, it is going to be a System Exception? Is it false?

Comment: Yes, it is false, since it contradicts the spec.

Comment: I am afraid your answer is only to some extend right. Every checked Exception is not an Application Exception. If it extends a Runtime Exception and it is not annotated with 'ApplicationException' it is merely a Runtime Exception, no need to be declared in throw clause of a method and it is treated by the Container as a System Exception.

Comment: Do you understand what a checked exception is? By definition, an exception that extends a Runtime exception, and that doesn't need to be declared in the throws clause, is not a checked exception. A checked exception is an exception that forces the developer to declare it in the throws clause. That's the definition of a "checked" exception: it's "checked" by the compiler.